# Python undetected_chromedriver in multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to create multithreading program for checking pages, but I cant to launch more than one browser at a time.

```
import from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import undetected_chromedriver
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import os
mainDir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)

def CreateBrowser():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=800,900")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=' + str(int(time.time())))
    driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(driver_executable_path=mainDir + '\\chromedriver.exe', browser_executable_path=f'{mainDir}\\utils\chrome\GoogleChromePortable\GoogleChromePortable.exe',
options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://google.com")
sleep(60)

driver.close()
driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   Thread(target=CreateBrowser).start()
   Thread(target=CreateBrowser).start()
```

Returns:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvKXf.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I used the Portable version and it was probably recompile and the launch was  chrome-portable.exe , and inside was a folder APP-bin-chrome.exe . I changed the launch path and everything started working perfectly